# Is there any way to check whether the given email is an active email or not in python

Tags: python-3.x, email-validation

I would like to know Is there any way to check that thee given email id is an active or not in python.
I have gone through 'validate_email' but it didn't give me the exact answer. It would be helpful if anyone help me out from this.

Comment: What do you mean with active?

Comment: Did you try validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True) with the verify parameter?

Comment: @trincot I mean the email accounts which are already been using

Comment: @JoshH I have tried validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True) but it didn't give me the required output. It is always showing true whatever the case may be.

Comment: Think about that. How would your python code know that (for example) I have recently sent an email to my colleague using my company's email address? Hint: the email never leaves my company's internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://github.com/scottbrady91/Python-Email-Verification-Script. This may cover most cases. Trincot has a good point though. If an email never leaves an internal network there's no way to know.